# DynamicJasper and OneToMany

Tags: javafx, dynamic-jasper

I have a two classes that are in OneToMany relationship:
Lager and supplier.

so when i have list of  objects, i have also object  and with standard java i can access fields of  object.

when i do this

```
AbstractColumn columnName = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                .setColumnProperty("name", String.class.getName())
                .setTitle("Name").setWidth(85)
                .build();
```

i get a good result, but when i do

```
AbstractColumn sellerColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
                .setColumnProperty("seller" ,Seller.class.getName() )
                .setTitle("seller").setWidth(85).build();
```

i just get toString method of my seller object, so my question is how to access field of seller when i am creating my DynamicJasper column

[image: example]

so i added now a picture to better

```
 @OneToMany(mappedBy ="seller", cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE,fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
public List<Lager> getLager() {
    return lager;
}

  @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "seller_id")
public Seller getSeller() {
    return seller.get();
}
```

this are the relations between these two objects, how could i just show name of my seller object, and not the entire toString method.

Comment: Any ideas, im pretty desperate , i checked all examples and found no guidline on how to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Well at the end i found a way, i changed following method :

```
AbstractColumn sellerColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("seller" ,Seller.class.getName() )
            .setTitle("seller").setWidth(85).build();
```

to

```
AbstractColumn sellerColumn = ColumnBuilder.getNew()
            .setColumnProperty("seller.seller_name" ,Seller.class.getName() )
            .setTitle("seller").setWidth(85).build();
```

after that everything worked, the thing is , i did try this, but for some reason my page did not load properly, when i did clean and build it worked flawlessly.

just to note that seller.seller_name is :

```
seller = my pojo class
```

and

```
seller_name
```

= my field that has getters and setters.